# Wordpress PHP what's doing the server at this moment?

Tags: php, wordpress, logging, server, load

I have a website (wordpress) published and it works perfectly, but from time to time it gets stuck. You try to enter the page and the server is like blocked, processing, and then for some minutes the website doesn't load.

I even added a cache system and performance optimizations, and the website is much faster now, but that keeps happening, from time to time (several times per day) the web is white, blank, loading for a long time.

I don't know what it is: a plugin? my code? it doesn't happen at a specific moment or action. So I can't identify when or where or why it happens.

So, can I somehow log the php code to know what is being executed at that moment? Where is the code stuck?

BTW, I already disabled the wp-cron. That's not it. And the web is huge so I can't start looking into every file for a loop or something, I need something faster.

Comment: "And the web is huge so I can't start looking into every file for a loop or something, I need something faster." If you're not willing to put in some effort, what makes you think that others will do it for you? Anyways, I'd start by looking at the slow query log. Having a look at the error log might be a good idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking on some query monitor which plugins / themes are responsible for the bottleneck. You can use GoDaddy's P3 Profiler plugin, which although it is not having updates, remains one of the best options for profiling a WordPress.

If you use cPanel, check the resource usage and try to identify patterns. For example, is the site slow at a specific time? On specific days of the week?

If you have access to Awstats or similar, you can check if there is any bot that accesses your site at some specific time.

If you treat only the symptom (slowness) you will continue to have the same problem. You need to find the source and then solve it at once.

Also check the access logs for detecting anomalies:
https://www.tecmint.com/find-top-ip-address-accessing-apache-web-server/

Looking on Google, I found some services that I think can help:

https://goupcloud.com [complete optimization and identification of bottlenecks (treatment in the cause and not symptom)]

https://www.wpfaster.org/ [full optimization]

https://www.wpspeedfix.com/ [full optimization]